# Is this the correct interpretation of my system logs BugCheckCode after a BSOD

Tags: windows, bsod

### I keep having blue screen...

...since a month approximately. For context it happens few days after getting a second screen (1080@60Hz + 2k@144Hz) ; installing a windows 10 update ; and mostly under stress (gaming mostly but not exclusively). No other hardware changes before. For more info on my build, [here it is detailed](https://pcpartpicker.com/list/8HNw9N)

### What I tried so far

*I already ask about this problem on reddit. [for reference](https://www.reddit.com/r/buildapc/comments/qicmlp/pc_rebooting_mid_game_after_secind_screen/)*

I recently updated to Windows 11 and have the same problem; I don't think Windows is causing my issue.

I thought about power problem but using different power consumption tools online it seems I should be all good.

My temps seems to not be the problem; I used [TechPowerUp GPU-Z](https://www.techpowerup.com/download/techpowerup-gpu-z/) to monitor my GPU. Just before the BSOD happens my GPU fan goes to 80% but the GPU is at 85°C max (92°C on the hotspot - don't know what it is but I've been told it's not the reference). The CPU is cooler than that so I really don't think it is the problem.

My secondary drive have some errors in its S.M.A.R.T attributes but games causing problems are not on this drive. I didn't checked further as I think if the disk was starting to die it would just disapear but I'm not sure about that.

### Where I'm at

I tried to check the system logs via the windows event viewer. But I'm not sure to interpret them correctly. I got in a span of 10 seconds (after rebooting i presume) an error, then a critical error then another error. That's all. I'll add the details of those below.

All I could find to help is relative to the second error (the one with the BugcheckCode); converting that `239` into hexadecimal we get `0xEF` and I found [this doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0xef--critical-process-died) relative to it. But I'm not sure converting it into hex is the way to proceed.

### What I need

Some help understanding those 3 errors.

1. Am I interpreting the second one correctly ?

1.2  If yes what futher step can i do to identify the exact problem ?

2. What about the first and third errors; are they giving any usable information ?
3. Is there any thing I may have missed that could be the solution ?

Thank you for taking the time <3

### Errors details

##### Error 1 - 22h26:52

Dump file creation failed due to error during dump creation.

```
- 
<Event
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- 
    <System>
        <Provider Name="volmgr" />
        <EventID Qualifiers="49156">161</EventID>
        <Version>0</Version>
        <Level>2</Level>
        <Task>0</Task>
        <Opcode>0</Opcode>
        <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
        <TimeCreated SystemTime="2021-11-25T21:26:52.9563012Z" />
        <EventRecordID>1419</EventRecordID>
        <Correlation />
        <Execution ProcessID="4" ThreadID="520" />
        <Channel>System</Channel>
        <Computer>MY_COMPUTER_NAME</Computer>
        <Security />
    </System>
- 
    <EventData>
        <Data>\Device\HarddiskVolume4</Data>
        <Binary>000000000100000000000000A10004C049000400010000C000000000000000000000000000000000</Binary>
    </EventData>
</Event>
```

##### Error 2 (critical) - 22h26:53

The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first. This error could be caused if the system stopped responding, crashed, or lost power unexpectedly.

```
- 
<Event
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- 
    <System>
        <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power" Guid="{331c3b3a-2005-44c2-ac5e-77220c37d6b4}" />
        <EventID>41</EventID>
        <Version>8</Version>
        <Level>1</Level>
        <Task>63</Task>
        <Opcode>0</Opcode>
        <Keywords>0x8000400000000002</Keywords>
        <TimeCreated SystemTime="2021-11-25T21:26:53.1109945Z" />
        <EventRecordID>1422</EventRecordID>
        <Correlation />
        <Execution ProcessID="4" ThreadID="8" />
        <Channel>System</Channel>
        <Computer>MY_COMPUTER_NAME</Computer>
        <Security UserID="S-1-5-18" />
    </System>
- 
    <EventData>
        <Data Name="BugcheckCode">239</Data>
        <Data Name="BugcheckParameter1">0xffffac8edc09e0c0</Data>
        <Data Name="BugcheckParameter2">0x0</Data>
        <Data Name="BugcheckParameter3">0x0</Data>
        <Data Name="BugcheckParameter4">0x0</Data>
        <Data Name="SleepInProgress">0</Data>
        <Data Name="PowerButtonTimestamp">0</Data>
        <Data Name="BootAppStatus">0</Data>
        <Data Name="Checkpoint">0</Data>
        <Data Name="ConnectedStandbyInProgress">false</Data>
        <Data Name="SystemSleepTransitionsToOn">0</Data>
        <Data Name="CsEntryScenarioInstanceId">0</Data>
        <Data Name="BugcheckInfoFromEFI">true</Data>
        <Data Name="CheckpointStatus">0</Data>
        <Data Name="CsEntryScenarioInstanceIdV2">0</Data>
        <Data Name="LongPowerButtonPressDetected">false</Data>
    </EventData>
</Event>
```

##### Error 3 - 22h27:02

**From the timestamp in the message, this one seems to be referencing the previous BSOD I got in the evening**

The previous system shutdown at 09:53:29 PM on ‎11/‎25/‎2021 was unexpected.

```
- 
<Event
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- 
    <System>
        <Provider Name="EventLog" />
        <EventID Qualifiers="32768">6008</EventID>
        <Version>0</Version>
        <Level>2</Level>
        <Task>0</Task>
        <Opcode>0</Opcode>
        <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
        <TimeCreated SystemTime="2021-11-25T21:27:02.7820360Z" />
        <EventRecordID>1411</EventRecordID>
        <Correlation />
        <Execution ProcessID="0" ThreadID="0" />
        <Channel>System</Channel>
        <Computer>MY_COMPUTER_NAME</Computer>
        <Security />
    </System>
- 
    <EventData>
        <Data>9:53:29 PM</Data>
        <Data>‎11/‎25/‎2021</Data>
        <Data />
        <Data />
        <Data>11</Data>
        <Data />
        <Data />
        <Binary>E5070B0004001900150035001D00B603E5070B0004001900140035001D00B6033C0000003C000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000</Binary>
    </EventData>
</Event>
```

Comment: First, eliminate the second display as the cause- just unplug it. Second, try to swap in another power supply - they may get weak (e.g., bad capacitors) with time. If neither of those eliminate the issue, try swapping a new HDD or SSD, is just to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit was a power cable extension on my gpu. plugin the power supply directly to the GPU solved it. I put abck the extensions at some point and the problem resurfaced soon after. So i definitely got rid of it and I did not have the problem in months.